# How do I remove this fuel line connection?

Tags: fuel-system, mazda-3

This one has me fooled.  I've never seen a quick connect like this without some mechanism to remove the connection.  Generally you push something, remove something or use a quick connect special tool to remove these types of connections.  This one I can't figure out.  If I push on the large white thing, it doesn't really move.  I'm assuming the white lock has to be removed, but I can't figure out how to pry it up. There are no access areas.  I tried a simple, gentle push on the small ends of the white lock with a jewelers flat tip screwdriver, no go there.

[image: Fuel connector one]

[image: Fuel Connector rotated view]

Anybody ever seen these before?  How do you remove the fuel line?

Note, I'm able to spin the connector about 90 degrees, as shown in the photos.

2nd note: after seeing these photos, I'm thinking I need to get the air gun in there first to blow all the sand and dust out of the area, BEFORE I try to disconnect the fuel line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out.

No go on using removal tools. I have access to a couple of different sets, but there isn't enough room.

[image: No room]

And no, you don't squeeze the sides either. The black plastic housing is way too stiff.

I played around with it.  I ended up using two screw drivers, one to push the white button, the other to GENTLY pry the connection away from its seated position.  There just isn't much room in this access panel to get your hands in there.

And here's how the doggone thing works.

[image: Press the button here]

[image: No press]

[image: Pressed]

Easy to do when its out of the car, sitting on the workbench. Info offered in case anybody else gets stuck on this fitting.

Comment: Great follow-through and pics!

Comment: "Easy to do when its out of the car, sitting on the workbench". Yep I hate that type of push on connector, wait until that plastic gets brittle, then they break, I don't know how many that came into my shop that had tie strips holding them on.

Answer (score 2):

That connector you squeeze the black part outer ring on two sides so that the ring moves out in two places to clear the white ears. From looking at the top photo - it shows the two white ears or pins.

And, good idea to clean first...

Answer (score 0):

This type LOOKS like you should press the white tabs but, in fact, that does not release the connector.  You need a FUEL LINE REMOVAL TOOL that slips over the line, pushes the tabs holding the line OUT, and then allows you to remove the connector.

Here is a video showing how these work:

[Fuel Line Removal Tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRTjYAxvaCs)

You can find these tools at any auto parts store, your favorite discount tool store, or your favorite online stores.

Comment: its not that type of connector.